# chef generate cookbook asking yes or no repeatedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef

I'm trying to create a chef cookbook using the following command:

```
chef generate cookbook cookbooks/create_files
```

on the following versions of chef

```
Chef Workstation version: 0.10.41
Chef Infra Client version: 15.4.45
Chef InSpec version: 4.18.0
Chef CLI version: 2.0.0
Test Kitchen version: 2.3.3
Cookstyle version: 5.9.3
```

I'm using an AWS ami recommended as part of the chef documentation. I have had one or two issues that I thought I had fully resolved from stopping and starting the machine on AWS which may not be related but just so you have full story.

The output I'm getting is:

```
> >> You must enter 'yes' or 'no'
> >> You must enter 'yes' or 'no'
> >> You must enter 'yes' or 'no'
> >> You must enter 'yes' or 'no'
...
```

and this is constantly being output, as the top line is flickering as if it is constantly being output.

I tried adding `-y` to the command to force accept yes but that doesn't seem to have changed anything. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After version 4 chef requires accepting of the licence. You can do that in one of two ways:

1. set an environment variable

   ```
   export CHEF_LICENSE="accept"
   ```

or

2. use "--chef-license accept" in the command line argument

Comment: The export option worked for me! Thanks!